# Programmatically adding reference gives run-time error

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I've written two VBA add-ins for `Excel (Office 2011, Mac)`: The first, 'basic' add-in also provides functions for the second add-in. There will also be other add-ins that use functions of the basic add-in in the future...
It should be possible to just run the basic plugin, with the second plugin being optional.

In the second plugin, I'm trying to add a reference like this:

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.VBE.VBProjects("SecondAddin").References.AddFromFile ("BasicAddin.xlam")
    UseFunctionFromBasicAddin
End Sub

Private Sub UseFunctionFromBasicAddin()
    FunctionFromBasicAddin
End Sub
```

However, this gives me a runtime error when starting Excel: `Run-time error 91: Object variable or With block variable not set.`

When I open the VBA editor after this error, I can see that the BasicAddin.xlam is now correctly referenced in the SecondAddin - and when I execute the `UseFunctionFromBasicAddin()` from within the VBA editor, it works. It just doesn't work when starting Excel.

When adding the reference in the VBA-editor (Tools->References), both add-ins are loaded, but there is a `MsgBox: "This workbook is currelty referenced by another workbook and cannot be closed."`

However, I want to add the reference programmatically since I suspect the link would break when using the plugins on a different computer with different paths?

I'd be glad for suggestions on how to get rid of the run-time error (or is there a better way of managing different add-ins?)...!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to modify the VBA project references of the current workbook.

Here is an ozgrid link that talks about removing broken references, and he says to do this programatically, you must do it from another workbook.

http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=23866

> Hi Barbara,
>
> 1 A reference ISMISSING is added to the workbook VB-project references.
>   (Should per se not be a problem unless You call it by code or try to install it then 
>   an error-message will be showed.
>
> **2 The below procedure must be executed from a different workbook and the target workbook must be open.**
>
> VB:

```
Sub Del_Broken_Ref() 
      'Add a reference to the Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility 5.3
     Dim VBReferens As VBIDE.Reference 
     Dim VBProjekt As VBIDE.VBProject 
     Dim stBok As String 

     stBok = Workbooks("Test.xls").Name 

     Set VBProjekt = Workbooks(stBok).VBProject 

     For Each VBReferens In VBProjekt.References 
         If VBReferens.IsBroken Then VBProjekt.References.Remove VBReferens 
     Next VBReferens 

 End Sub
```

> If running Excel 2002 and above You must allow access to VB-projects via Tools - Macros... - Security.
>
> [Edit] If the add-ins VB-project is closed then You are out of luck...